# Filter NLTK Bigram Frequency (Python3, NLTK)

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I have a code that goes like this:

```
df1 = df[['term']]
df2 = df1.to_string()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(df2)
bgs = nltk.bigrams(words)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
```

How do I now filter fdist to only find those bigrams that appear more than 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for my purposes (not the most direct, but I figured I would add my two cents): put the data into a new data frame, filtered in the dataframe

```
frequencies = [[" ".join(k),v] for k,v in fdist.items()]
frame = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['Bigrams','Frequency'])
removal = frame[frame['Frequency'] >= 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

try ...

```
for obj in fdist.most_common():
    if obj[1] >2:
        print(obj)
```

## OR

```
for obj in fdist:
    if fdist1[obj] >2:
        print(obj, fdist1[obj])
```